# Using tqdm with subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

I'm trying to add a progress bar feature to an open-source project I contribute to. This software multi-threads commands passed to it, in an easy to use way. At the moment, I am trying to add a progress bar functionality to the application, however am unable to get the progress bar to stick to the bottom and update.

We are using the following code to process commands:

```py
subprocess.call(task, shell=True)
```

I currently use `tqdm.update()` to update the progress of the bar, however that keeps printing on a new line, making the terminal look horrible.
[image: Image displaying non-sticky progress bar]

To see exactly how we have used the tqdm package, please see the link below:
https://github.com/codingo/Interlace/blob/master/Interlace/lib/threader.py

Finally, our aim for this application is having a progress bar stuck to the bottom of the terminal, so that it doesn't affect the output and looks reasonably clean. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please do not expect people to go off site to answer your question. Post a minimal example that would be useful to others with the same problem if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patched the issue by changing the following:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def run_task(task):
        subprocess.call(task, shell=True)
```

into:

```py
    @staticmethod
    def run_task(task, t):
        s = subprocess.Popen(task, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        t.write(s.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8"))
```

This basically allows us to pipe all of the output of our task into stdout and then decode the bytes using UTF-8 and print it out using tqdm.write()

Worked like a charm!

Comment: what is that new parameter t? How do you call that run_task method now?

Comment: @gg99 As from the code that is linked in the question, `t` is a `tqdm` instance. The `tqdm` package (https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) is often used to produce progress bars in Python.